# Getting IR codes from rooted android box

Tags: 7.1-nougat

I have a rooted Android 7.1 box probably rebranded (Amlogic S905W I think) with an IR remote that's unreliable and battery hungry, I'd like to configure the remote on my phone with IR blaster but I have no idea what the IR codes are, is this available on the device? I've found out a remote.conf file but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it if it's useful.